# Two errors on calling the method and printing out the information I'm using netbeans

Tags: java, file, methods, printing

I'm getting two errors on this code. One on the last line on the `System.out.println` and one when i'm calling the method. How would I make this code work with this file? Here is my code:

```
package practicefile;

/**
 *
 * @author jahkeyshagodwin
 */
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Practicefile {
//import java.util.*;
    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    * @throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws FileNotFoundException {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("hotel.txt"));
       PrintStream(Scanner (input));

    }

   public static void PrintStream(Scanner input) {
       while (input.hasNext()) {
            String name = input.next();
            double sum = 0.0;
            while (input.hasNextDouble()) {
              sum += input.nextDouble();
          }
        } System.out.println("Total hours worked by" + name + " = " + sum);

    }

 }
```

The stack trace reads:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: practicefile.Practicefile.Scanner
>
> at practicefile.Practicefile.main(Practicefile.java:23)
>   /Users/jahkeyshagodwin/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53:
>
> Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Comment: "*I'm getting two errors on this code.*" - Compile errors? Exceptions? Please be precise and include the compiler errors/stack traces.

Comment: Cannot find symbol

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the full compiler error (the compiler is quite verbose, it says which file, which line and even which character caused the error).

Answer (score 1):

One problem you have is with the line

```
PrintStream(Scanner (input));
```

The correct syntax for what you are trying to do is:

```
PrintStream(input);
```

Second is that in your loop you declare the variables name and sum. However because you declared them inside the loop, they do not exist outside the loop. If you change it to:

```
 public static void PrintStream(Scanner input) {
   String name = "";
   double sum = 0.0;
   while (input.hasNext()) {
        name = input.next();           
        while (input.hasNextDouble()) {
          sum += input.nextDouble();
      }
    } System.out.println("Total hours worked by" + name + " = " + sum);

}
```

It should work.

Comment: The declaration error went away( Thank you) but the calling the method is still giving me an error.

Comment: cannot find symbol